# Could Not Be Accessed Value Of The For Loop Counter In PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad, plsql-developer

I try to learn PL/SQL for loops in tutorials. I learn flow of control in a for loops. (And i saw that it is same with most of the other programming languages)

**Here is the flow of control in a for loop:**

> 1. The initial step is executed first, and only once. This step allows
>    you to declare and initialize any loop control variables.

> 2. Next, the condition, i.e., initial_value .. final_value is evaluated.
>    If it is TRUE, the body of the loop is executed. If it is FALSE, the
>    body of the loop does not execute and flow of control jumps to the
>    next statement just after the for loop.

> 3. After the body of the for loop executes, the value of the counter
>    variable is increased or decreased.

> 4. The condition is now evaluated again. If it is TRUE, the loop
>    executes and the process repeats itself (body of loop, then increment
>    step, and then again condition). After the condition becomes FALSE,
>    the FOR-LOOP terminates.

And then i  want to test this steps for my worry in my TOAD IDE. I use simple sample code to test as below.

```
DECLARE
   a number(2) ;
BEGIN
   FOR a IN REVERSE 10 .. 20 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value of a: ' || a);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Now this loop start initial counter, initial_value and final_value. counter is 'a', initial_value is 10 and the final_value is 20. And the counter a  will be the first in 20 because of the REVERSE keyword. The loop body is executed for 20. After the body is executed a is decreased. And it will be 19. And then the condition is eveluated. The condition is true because of 19 is in [10, 20]. and then for loop body is executed. This operations is contiuned at the same way. When counter a's value is 9 and then condition evaluated to FALSE.And then the loop is terminated. Flow of control jumps to the next statement just after the for loop.The counter's last value is 9. And i want to see it 9 value. so that i run below code.

```
DECLARE
   a number(2) ;
BEGIN
   FOR a IN REVERSE 10 .. 20 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value of a: ' || a);
   END LOOP;
   dbms_output.put_line('THE FINAL VALUE OF a: ' || a);
END;
/
```

When the above code is executed, it produces the following result:

```
value of a: 20
value of a: 19
value of a: 18
value of a: 17
value of a: 16
value of a: 15
value of a: 14
value of a: 13
value of a: 12
value of a: 11
value of a: 10
THE FINAL VALUE OF a:
```

But i hope see the result like as below:

```
value of a: 20
value of a: 19
value of a: 18
value of a: 17
value of a: 16
value of a: 15
value of a: 14
value of a: 13
value of a: 12
value of a: 11
value of a: 10
THE FINAL VALUE OF a: 9
```

Why the counter 'a' is not connected after the loop. Why I did not see it's value to 9. Does'nt the <strike>program</strike> compiler made a real way assignment to counter 'a' ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `a` that you declare in your declaration section is not the same as the variable `a` that is declared in the context of your loop.  You've declared two different variables named `a` with different scope.

If you run your block without a declaration section, you'll notice that it works even though you aren't declaring a variable `a` in the declaration section.  When you write a `for` loop, your counter is implicitly declared and is in scope only within the loop.  After the `end loop`, you can no longer reference the variable.

```
BEGIN
   FOR a IN REVERSE 10 .. 20 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('value of a: ' || a);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

If you want to explicitly declare the variable you are using in your loop and you want to be able to reference the variable outside the loop, you could write a `while` loop

```
declare
  i integer;
begin
  i := 20;
  while i >= 10
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( 'In loop: ' || i );
    i := i - 1;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Final value: ' || i );
end;
```